# How to reset the Icarus Go E600BK

Tags: hardware

I have an Icarus Go E600BK ereader.

It has worked since years. But recently, whenever I open a book and go to the next page,  it restarts and goes back to the opening menu.

I cannot find any information about this company.

I searched for the manual online, and it only says that one can do a "pinhole reset". I am not sure I do it correctly: when I insert a push pin for 20", it goes very deep, the black text on the screen gets thinner, but nothing else happens. After I restart the device with the on/off button, the problem still persists.

What can I do? Would it be possible to open the ereader and see if the pinhole reset has moved inside?